# How to get soap API response using objective-c

Tags: objective-c

How to get response for soap API using objective-c , which uses raw and XML(text/xml) for body.

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRuB4_Zx9M2wkOlSyg4IE6bB-kk65qI5pEdOBqzQ3BC-cOqSuGmOrUMRgu-

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
        @"<soap:Body>\n"
        @"<login xmlns=\"http://webservice.collatt.com/\">\n"
                  @"<collid>%@</collid>\n"
                  @"<wru>%@</wru>\n"
                  @"<userid>%@</userid>\n"
                  @"<password>%@</password>\n"
                  @"</login>\n"
                  @"</soap:Body>\n"
                  @"</soap:Envelope>\n",str1,str2,str3,str4];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservice.collatt.com/collatt_json.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //Handle your response here
    if(data != nil){
        NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

        NSLog(@"login response%@",responseDict); //I am not getting response here



    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: try adding your code into the question, it's not a good practice to link to a picture of the code

Comment: You post XML and receive JSON? "//I am not getting response here": Did you pass `if(data != nil)`? `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`. Please, there is an error parameter, use it ! Do not put nil instead!. Could you do `NSString *str = [NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`, log it and check on a JSON validator if it's valid?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
        @"<soap:Body>\n"
        @"<login xmlns=\"http://webservice.collatt.com/\">\n"
                  @"<collid>%@</collid>\n"
                  @"<wru>%@</wru>\n"
                  @"<userid>%@</userid>\n"
                  @"<password>%@</password>\n"
                  @"</login>\n"
                  @"</soap:Body>\n"
                  @"</soap:Envelope>\n",str1,str2,str3,str4];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservice.collatt.com/collatt_json.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:theRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"dataTaskWithRequest error: %@", error);
    } else if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

        if (statusCode != 200) {
            NSError *parseError;
            id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
            NSLog(@"responseobject is %@",responseObject);

        } else {
            NSError *parseError;
            id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

            NSLog(@"else condtion");
            if (!responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"JSON parse error: %@", parseError);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"responseobject is %@",responseObject);
                //[self MainService:responseObject];
            }

            //if response was text/html, you might convert it to a string like so:
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"final responseString = %@", responseString);

        }
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

Comment: What that code? Why does this solve your issue? What are the results?

Answer (score 0):

Use **NSXMLParser** for getting response. You cannot use **NSJSONSerialization** for getting response. Your request is SOAP-XML so 
 response SOAP-XML.